# VS Code: Recompile every SASS file in folder on save

Tags: sass, vscode-extensions

I use `Live Sass Compiler` with VS Code and want to compile all SASS files when I save something.

Currently it compiles only the file I work in. But as I work with variables and several smaller SASS files, changes to these have no effect on other files they are used in.

Example:
`config.scss`

```
$white: #FFF;
$yellow: #FFED00;
$black: #000;
```

`main.scss`

```
@import "config.scss";

#header { 
  background: $yellow;
}
```

*Problem:*
When I change the yellow color in `config.scss` and save it, the `main.scss` won't be compiled. To get the changed color into the `$yellow` variable I have to save `main.scss` which is annoying und uncomfortable.

Answer (score 0):

Meanwhile I found the answer. If you want all files to be saved and have included files, all included files have to start with _